PowerShell User-guided script to change NetworkCategory
I'd like to write a short PowerShell Script where firstly a list of network adapters appear, thereafter the User has to select one of these networks and after that the NetworkCategory is switched to private.
Right now I'm doing this manually with the commands

Get-NetconnectionProfile
and
Set-NetconnectionProfile

This works fine to me but this process is used by different Users on different PCs with different "InterfaceIndices" or "NetworkNames" so I'd like to make it a bit more Userfriendly and automatically.
I'm very new to PowerShell so I've no idea were to start. Any suggestions?
I tried this to show the available Networks, but I don't know how to make a User seleciton out of this:
$net = Get-NetConnectionProfile
for ( $index = 0; $index -lt $net.count; $index++)
{
 " [{0}]"  -f $index+ $Tab  +$net[$index].name 

}


You should be able to use PowerShell with WPF and dynamic XAML to do this. You will likely need to use get-netadapter to list all adapters though I think.

First of all I would suggest using a foreach loop instead.
This is because if Get-NetConnectionProfile returns only one profile there would be no count method, cause it ain't an array.
(You can check this with $net.getType() and $net | Get-Member)
If for some reason you need to use the for loop you could explicitly declare the var to be a cim instance array like this:
[CimInstance[]]$net = Get-NetConnectionProfile

Back to your question:
To get user input usually the Read-Host cmdlet is used.
But for your specific case I would recommend looking at Out-GridView -PassThru
$selection = $net | Out-GridView -PassThru

